# Converting multidimensional array into arrays in list for every row

Tags: python, numpy

I have a data set like this,

```
data = np.array([[ 5, 31, 61],
                 [ 10, 31, 67],
                 [ 15, 31, 69],
                 [ 4, 31, 72],
                 [ 14, 31, 73],
                 [ 21, 31, 77],
                 [ 19, 31, 78]])
```

I want to convert it into arrays in list for every single row. I tried,

```
np.split(data,len(data))

#[array([[ 5, 31, 61]]),
# array([[10, 31, 67]]),
# array([[15, 31, 69]]),
# array([[ 4, 31, 72]]),
# array([[14, 31, 73]]),
# array([[21, 31, 77]]),
# array([[19, 31, 78]])]
```

But as you can see it gives double `[` to me. What I simply want is;

```
[np.array([5, 31, 61]),
np.array([10, 31, 67]),
np.array([15, 31, 69]),
np.array([4, 31, 72]),
np.array([14, 31, 73]),
np.array([21, 31, 77]),
np.array([19, 31, 78])]
```

Comment: Wonder why you would need a format like this ? You can simply use  a loop to get what you need `[data[i] for i in range(len(data))]`

Comment: The format is necessary for a script I use in somewhere else. I always stop myself from using loops in python. That is why I tried `np.split`.  But I think sometimes it is good to use it since it does the job simply in here. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Split does a loop.  It's making a list.  Have you tried `list(data)`?

Comment: [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) works too but it seems not to be optimized for OP's case. `[*data]` is optimized the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about taking advantage of unpacking?

```
lst = [*data]
```

or:

```
lst = list(data)
```

output:

```
[array([ 5, 31, 61]),
 array([10, 31, 67]),
 array([15, 31, 69]),
 array([ 4, 31, 72]),
 array([14, 31, 73]),
 array([21, 31, 77]),
 array([19, 31, 78])]
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.split` could be applied too but you are required to do it one-dimensionally. So you might like to create a one-dimensional view of your data first:

```
%%timeit
data_ravel = data.ravel()
out = np.split(data_ravel, len(data))
>>> 14.5 µs ± 337 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Note that creating a view is costless (it took 0.13 µs on my computer)

Internally, it's being done like so:

```
out = []
div_points = range(0, data.size+1, data.shape[1])
start = div_points[:-1]
end = div_points[1:]
out = list(data_ravel[i:j] for i,j in zip(start, end))
>>> 2.31 µs ± 44.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Note that it's faster because I'd doing a couple of optimisations here:

- using range instead of `np.array`
- using lazy list comprehension instead of `list.append`

However, it can't compete with classical methods like in @mozway 's answer. They are optimal:

```
%%timeit
out = [*data]
>>> 902 ns ± 8.09 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit
out = list(data)
>>> 979 ns ± 12.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit
out = [n for n in data]
>>> 1.04 µs ± 14.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit
out = list(n for n in data)
>>> 1.37 µs ± 80.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```